# MySql Command not found : MacOS

Tags: mysql, bash, unix, terminal, macos-catalina

I'm new to using the terminal and I'm having trouble troubleshooting the following issue:
After looking at some other similar problems I've tried the following commands that might enlighten you to what is wrong. 
First I'll post a summary of the things I've tried in the terminal and the responses I got from the terminal. Below that I'll "briefly" write about installation process and workbench issue.

**(MyUserName)$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql usr/local/bin**

**Password:**

- (I input my Mac password here)*

**ln: usr/local/bin: No such file or directory**

Sometimes I get "No such file or directory" but sometimes I get the following:

**(MyUserName)$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin**

**ln: /usr/local/bin: File exists**

- I still can't access mysql though, even if I try straight after the "File Exists" reply.
  Perhaps I messed something up yesterday when I did the above command but forgot the "s" after the dash?

**(MyUsername)$ ls /usr/local/mysql**

**LICENSE       README      bin     data        docs        include     keyring     lib     man     share       support-files**

**(MyUsername)$ echo $PATH**

**/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local//bin**

- Something I tried because of similar questions*

**(MyUsername)$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local//bin**

- I just got another prompt from the terminal and tried the following login after that:*

**(MyUserName)$ mysql -u root -p**

**-bash: mysql: command not found**

I have successfully installed mysql and workbench and used it with no problem, however I just factory reset my MacBook and when installing again, I'm having these problems. 
At first I noticed that the default shell in the terminal was zsh, and I changed it to be default bash because I wasn't sure the commands were the same, and I am learning from a video and he uses the bash shell.

When installing mysql, I was not allowed to change the path or change where it was installed, not that I would've done so, but perhaps that's weird?

I also did not get to choose anything else except the type of password and then setting the password. (I remember choosing which components or something when doing this before)

In workbench, my root server says it's running, when I try to make another connection everything seems normal except that there is no input field for the password. So I've tried making the connection anyway but when trying to use it, it asks me for a password, where my root password does not work.

I appreciate all the help I can get, I need this for my studies (Teacher couldn't help due to the OS). Please let me know if you have any suggestions, thanks :)!

Comment: To be clear did you install using Brew or the Mysql Installer?

Answer (score 1):

Your command should have been:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

Basically, the command does a symbolic link for the mysql binary in /usr/local/bin which is already in your search path.
Alternatively you could have added '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql' to PATH

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I see the mistake I did there, but it still doesn't work if I do that:

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
Password:
ln: /usr/local/bin/mysql: Not a directory